# how will the code execution be done inside asp.net c# (IF, else IF , IF ,IF)

Tags: c#

i am working on an asp.net mvc 5 web application. now I have the following :-

```
    IF(condition1)
{
//1
}
    else if (condition 2)
{
//2
}
    IF(condition3)
{
//3
}
    IF(condition4)
{
//4
}
```

so how will this be executed inside my application ?
will the follow be as follow:-

1. if condition1 passed then conditio2 will never be checked , while condition 3 & condition4 will always be checked ? if condition1 failed , then condition2 will be checked and also condition3 & 4 will be checked ?

Comment: Why are you tagging this as asp.net ?!

Comment: Why not test it yourself.

Comment: Is there a reason for using no brackets or semi-colons in that attempt at code? Without that it may well be interpreted different than you'd want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a bit of indentation to your code will clear your problem

```
// Test values, change them to change the output
int c1 = 1;
int c2 = 2;
int c3 = 3;
int c4 = 4;

if(c1 == 1)
    Console.WriteLine("Condition1 is true");
else if (c2 == 2)
    if(c3 == 3)
        if(c4 == 4)
            Console.WriteLine("Condition2,3 and 4 are true");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Condition4 is false but 3 and 2 are true");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Condition3 is false but 2 is true");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Condition1 and 2 are false");
```

In your example there are no curly braces to delimit blocks of statements to be executed if the conditions are true, so the ifs end at the first semicolon.

When `condition1` is true nothing in the else chain will be evaluated because both ifs on `condition3` and `4` depends on the `condition1` being false and `condition2` being true.

If `condition1` is false then `condition2` is evaluated and, if true, the code goes to check `condition3` and goes to check `condition4` if `condition3` is true,

Of course, depending on what actions you need to perform on the input values this could be written simply as

```
if(c1 == 1)
    Console.WriteLine("Condition1 is true");
else if (c2 == 2 && c3 == 3 && c4 == 4)
    Console.WriteLine("Condition2,3, and 4 are true");
```

**EDIT**

After adding the braces now the code behavior is totally different

```
if(condition1)
{
    // enters here if condition1 is true, thus the condition2 is not evaluated
}
else if (condition 2)
{
    // enters here if condition1 is evaluated and is false, 
    // but the condition2 is true 
}


if(condition3)
{
   // enters here if condition3 is true, indipendently from the
   // result of the evaluation of condition1 and 2 
}
if(condition4)
{
   // enters here if condition3 is true, indipendently from the
   // result of the evaluation of condition1 and 2 
}
```

Comment: Well, now is different. Condition3 and Condition4 are no more chained to the evaluation of Condition2 and are Always evaluated both in case of Condition1 and Condition2 being false or true

Answer (score 0):

3 and 4 will always be checked. 1 gets checked and if true then 2 is ignored as it is under an `else if` though if 1 is `false` then 2 will be evaluated.